# QSqlTableModel обновление/добавление данных

Tags: qt

Мне нужно добавить одну запись в таблицу при всплывающем диалоге (в котором ввожу данные).
Какой из вариантов правильный:

1. Сделать сразу SQL запрос INSERT, и потом сделать model->select() (чтобы данные QTableView обновились)
2. Добавить строку в модель model->insertRow() и после этого сделать submitAll()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше через модель (ваш вариант 2).

А ещё лучше расскажите, что вы делаете такое, что у вас есть диалоговое окно, которое вы наследуете от QWidget и значение из которого вы, осмелюсь предположить, записываете в базу. Просто может быть вам лучше подойдут делегаты или QDataWidgetMapper.

Comment: Все правильно, значение записывается в базу. Думаю пока что нет. А в чем будет отличие?

Comment: Сложно сказать, так как я не знаю подробностей, а значит и того, что вам нужно. Я же просто предположил и предложил рассказать.
Ну вообще как минимум в уменьшении коэффициента велосипедности)

Comment: Пока что пользователю нужно добавить запись у которой один атрибут. Я сделал диалог с полем ввода. Мне этого достаточно.